# Separating database results into categories

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL database with a table called product. Columns are id, product_name, price, category. I use PDO with fetchAll and sort by category. I would like to create HTML tables for each category grouping. In the past I've always done something like this:

```
$category = "";
$html = "";
foreach($results as $row){
    if ($row['category'] != $category){
        if ($category != "")
            $html .= "</table>";
        $category = $row['category'];
        $html .= "<table>";
     }
     //code for table row here
}
$html .= "</table>";
```

However, I am wondering if there is a different way to do this such as splitting an array by categories and running a foreach on each sub-array. Is this possible?

**Edit:**

To explain further, I am looking for something that is not as cumbersome. I prefer not having to check what the previous category was (or if it was empty). I prefer not having to specify a closing `</table>` tag twice. If an array can be split by category then this would get around these issues by just running a nested loop on each of the categories.

**Edit 2:**

For some reason this question was listed as opinion based. Can someone inform me as to what is opinion based about my question? I will then try to improve it.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain further what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can someone please explain why my question is "opinion-based"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to skip the whole category check then yes, you could create a new array.

```
$productCategories = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $productCategories[$result['cat']][] = $result;
}

foreach ($productCategories as $productCategory) {
    // Start table
    foreach ($productCategory as $product) {
        // Render product
    }
    // End table
}
```